# Find word that does not come after another word with RegEx

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

What is the RegEx pattern I should use in order to match a specific word that does not come after another specific word?

For example:

I'm looking for an "abc" that does not come after "xyz", so the following will match:

```
xxabc

p abc
```

And the following will not:

```
xyz abc
```

Thanks!

Comment: These answers make use of negative look behind - which is fine, but be aware not all Regex engines support this. JavaScript regex, for example, does not.

Comment: Do you want it to fail matching if `xyz` is immediately before `abc` or _anywhere_ before `abc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!xyz)(?<!xyz )abc
```

Your variation in spacing between letter groups, however, suggests that you might see some variation in distance between `abc` and `xyz`. If you only want to find abc if it is **never** preceded by xyz earlier in the string, then you may need something more along the lines of this:

```
^(?!xyz)*((?!xyz).)*abc
```

The latter regular expression uses [an equivalent of inverse matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) rather than a negative lookbehind assertion.

Comment: This answer would be worth an upvote just for being the only one to offer a solution that doesn't involve lookbehinds.  But I don't see why you need both `(.(?!xyz))*` and `((?!xyz).)*`, especially given that the first one is broken.  When you put the dot in front of the lookahead, it doesn't start filtering until the second character.  That's why your regex incorrectly matches the string `"xyz abc"`.

Comment: @Alan Moore, Excellent point. Thanks for catching that. I modified the first parenthetical expression, so that its primary purpose is to catch xyz in the event that xyz immediately precedes abc (without any intervening characters). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
(?<!xyz )abc
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/UU1H9b2ICOvD0K2H)

But syntax will vary, depending on the language you are using.  For example, this syntax won't work in JavaScript.